# Creating list with lists inside by using multiply

Tags: python, list

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = [a*2]
>>> b
[[]]
>>> b = [copy.deepcopy(a)*2]
>>> b
[[]]
```

I'm trying to create `b` to be a list consisting of two copies of `a`. Why is `b` not `[[],[]]`? And how can I make it so that `b` is `[[],[]]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to create b with `a` in it *twice*:

```
a = []
b = [a] * 2
```

But beware, lists are [mutable](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html)!

```
b[1].append('foo')
b
[['foo'], ['foo']]
```

If you want to create b with two *copies* of `a`:

```
b = [a[:] for i in range(2)]
```

For finer control over the nature of copies (vs bindings), read the python [copy](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) module documentation.

Comment: Thank you for trying to head off another shallow copy question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `b = [a for i in xrange(2)]`

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying a list * 2, is the same as adding it to itself, as expected. But if you do:

```
a = [1]
b = [2]
a + b
[1, 2]
```

Note that you don't get `[[1], [2]]` - that's not what adding a list together means. Adding two lists gives you a list with all elements from both lists in it.

So, on those lines, `[] * 2` generates a list like `[]`, because that's what you would also get if you did `[] + []` - a list with all elements from both lists in it, which, since both input lists are empty, is also empty. And then, you put it inside another list, to end up with `[[]]`.

The other answers already cover other ways to generate this, so i won't duplicate those.